# Ordering the records based on one-to-many joined table in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

I have two tables Table1 and Table2. Table2 contains foreign key to Table1. So there is one-to-many mapping b/w Table1 and Table2. Now I want to fetch records from Table1  in following way:

```
from Table1 t1 left join t1.table2s order by t1.table2.id asc
```

Basically I need to get those records from Table1 on top which have not been joined with Table2(This means Table2 doesn't have any record which references that particular record in Table1). Is there any right or simple way to do this in hibernate?

Comment: got the answer: from Table1 t1 left join t1.table2s as t2 order by t2 asc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query is wrong.

Correct query is

```
from Table1 t1 left join t1.table2s as t2 order by t2.id asc
```